# Admob stop serving ads to my android app after i renamed the app in google play

Tags: android, mobile, admob, ads, adsense

I simply renamed the app in my google play console and since that day the app is no more generating revenue! i then focused on the analytics and i noticed since the day i renamed the app in google play console, there is no more ads displayed in my app.

I tried to change the name to the old one but ad still not displaying, i also checked adsense account and there is no warning of not respecting rules.

My question is this

After renaming an app in the google play console, is there any other changes i have to make. or how can i fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Ad delivery has nothing to do with anything in Google Play Console. It is solely driven by the AdUnitId you have in your app.

You must have also changed something in your app, or something in your Admob account.